# Query with TAKE and check if it is null

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get information from a Cosmos DB, and I want to get an amount of rows or all rows. User can type 100, for example, and he will get only 100 rows and if he doesn't type anything he will get all rows.

Before I got the information with .Take()
For example: .Take(amount), but if amount is null I have a fail.

With:

```
.Take(amount)
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
.TakeIf(amount != null, amount);
```

I know the lines above are wrong but this is the idea.

And the lines below are the complete query.

```
var resultDTO = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<DTO>(
     UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(idDatabase, idCollection), queryOptions)
     .WhereIf(sourceId != null, x => x.sourceId == sourceId)
     .Take(amount)
     .AsEnumerable()
     .ToList();
```

How can I check if amount is null or not?

Comment: What is the type of `Amount`?

Comment: @mjwills is an int?, an int nulleable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is deeper thank just configuring the expression. CosmosDB only returns paginated results by default. If you use the synchronized `AsEnumerable().ToList()` approach your code will go through all the pages in a synchronous fashion. This will lead to terrible performance. What you wanna do is iterate and collect. Sadly there is no fancy way to go about this.

Sadly, you cannot encapsulate all the necessary code in a `TakeIf` call because there is more that needs to happen during querying.

Here is a code example.

```
var amount = 100;

var queryOptions = new RequestOptions {
    MaxItemCount = 100
};

var queryable = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<DTO>(
     UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(idDatabase, idCollection), queryOptions)
     .WhereIf(sourceId != null, x => x.sourceId == sourceId);


if(amount != null && amount > 0){
    queryable.Take(amount);
}

var documentQuery = queryable.AsDocumentQuery();

var results = new List<DTO>();
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    if (amount != null && amount > 0 && results.Count == amount)
        break;

    var items = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<DTO>(cancellationToken);

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        results.Add(item);

        if (amount != null && amount > 0 && results.Count == amount)
            break;
    }
}
return results;
```

In this example I am assuming that you only wanna add the `Take` call when the amount is not null and it is more than 0. If that's not the case then remove the `> 0` checks.

For a more detailed example on this check [Cosmonaut's source code here](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/blob/develop/src/Cosmonaut/Extensions/CosmosResultExtensions.cs#L228).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var bob = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<DTO>( UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(idDatabase, idCollection), queryOptions)
    .WhereIf(SourceId != null, x => x.SourceId == SourceId);

var resultDTO = Amount == null ? bob.ToList() : bob.Take(Amount.Value).ToList();
```

This will apply the `Take` **only if `Amount` is not `null`**.

*If that doesn't work, try using `.AsEnumerable()` before `.ToList()`.*

Comment: I thought to do this, but it has a bad performance. For example if it isn't the same get only 100 than  get 1.000.000 and after return only 100

Comment: I don't understand what that comment means @CMorillo.

Comment: You are suggestion me to get all information and return the required amount alone . But if you have many rows in the database, you are not interested in get all information because it will take a lot of time @mjwills